# How can I reinstall the WinRM service on WS2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, winrm

Whatever winrm command I issue I get,

> The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request
>   ... Error number:  -2144108526 0x80338012

I checked all the usual suspects.  The service is running.  All updates have been applied.

I would like to uninstall the WinRM service and reinstall but I can't find WinRM listed as a "Windows Feature".  Is there a way to reset/reinstall this function?

This is a newly installed Standard Windows 2012 server.  It was upgraded from Windows 2008 RS Web Server.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall? `winrm quickconfig` will add the firewall exception for you. Also, are you getting the error connecting to the 2012 server with WinRM or a client from the server?

Comment: @Cole Yes the firewall rules appear good.  I get the error when doing `winrm quickconfig` on the WS2012 server itself.

Comment: Check your http.sys: `netsh http show iplist` to confirm that you are listening on the loopback address. if not, add 127.0.0.1 to the list of listeners.

Comment: @Cole That fixed it. Thanks.  I was hunting around the url reservations but I had forgotten about the iplist.  If you add your comment as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your http.sys: `netsh http show iplist` to confirm that you are listening on the loopback address. if not, add 127.0.0.1 to the list of listeners.

Comment: netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to an old IP in the iplist.
You can remove IP addresses with the following command:

`netsh http delete iplisten 10.0.0.0`

Answer (score -2):

In my case it happened when I promoted stand alone server to DC. It was some strange issue with Network Service account that WinRM service are using. I set the service to use local account (which seems quite stupid for domain controller) and have got an error, then I set again to use network service. Then started the service, ran WinRM quickconfig and it works.